# Deserializer Json Format DateTime

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, serialization, system.text.json

I want to read this field from my JSON:

```
create_date: "2020-06-07 15:24:23"
```

This is the property in my class

```
public DateTime? expire_date { get; set; }
```

But this method `JsonSeializer.Deserialize` can't map this and I get this exception:

> The converter specified on 'expire_date' does not derive from JsonConverter or have a public parameterless constructor

Comment: It should just work. How have you customized your serializer? In other words, provide code

Comment: it can`t work but try this sulotion but it does not work

Comment: https://blog.kulman.sk/custom-datetime-deserialization-with-json-net/

Comment: Instead of headbangingly asserting that it doesn't work, why don't you provide your code? Also, That tutorial you linked is for `Newtonsoft.Json` but your are using `System.Text.Json`

Comment: yes!! you say correct TNX

Comment: Please, provide the complete code and json

Answer (score -1):

Declare your expire_date as a string if u can.
 If u cant do that define a new class with same variables except expire_date . Define expire_date as a string in new class . Than deserialize object with new class. After that u can parse string datetime value and assign your class.

Comment: Bad advise. Why would you do this when DateTime support is built and he is using the apis incorrectly.